Can a hypothetically massless object/particle of finite size spin around its own center in a fixed position in space?
Imagine a hypothetically spinning massless object or particle of finite size. I am not referring to orbital spin but spinning around its own center like a flywheel spinning with a fixed center. This particle will have theoretically zero angular momentum $L$ because it has no mass.
Does this mean that it cannot remain spinning in a fixed rest position in space even if no any external force is applied?
OR,
Does this mean that this hypothetically massless physical spinning particle of finite size is impossible to exist according to quantum mechanics and relativity theory?
Will the energy-mass equivalence play a role here $E=mc^2$ and the particle will still posses an effective rest mass therefore also an effective angular momentum and it will remain spinning in a fixed position in space?
I am interested in an answer especially under the context angular momentum is used in particle physics and in general, Quantum Mechanics.
Note: Assume there is no external gravitational field applied to the object and is happily spinning in a vacuum. A canonical answer is preferred.

What you are describing is physically impossible.
Massless fundamental particles exist, like photons and gluons, and indeed they have a spin though this is a quantum mechanical property and not related to any motion of the particle. However a macroscopic massless object would have to be made up from a bound state of massless particles, and this bound state would not be massless since its energy would give it a mass courtesy of Einstein's famous equation $E = mc^2$.
Given that a macroscopic massless object cannot exist it is meaningless to ask what its angular momentum is. We could make up some equations to try and describe it, but this would be science fiction not physics.
A massive object made up from massless particles could in principle be made, and a kugelblitz would be an example. This could indeed have a spin since its angular momentum would be the (vector) sum of the angular momenta of all the photons that make it up.

There's a few challenges here.  First off, a hypothetical particle will do what a hypothetical particle does.  Without specifying which particle is involved, we really can't say what happens.
The next important thing is that Newtonian physics only applies to massfull objects.  It does not attempt to explain the behavior of massless particles.  So it's not that Newtonian physics would say angular momentum is 0, it would say that the physics simply doesn't apply.
The concept of the angular momentum operator in quantum physics is similar in form to the angular momentum of Netwonian physics, but is not associated with what you or I would call "spinning."
An interesting hypothetical question to pose in return might be "how do you know it is spinning?"  What properties of the particle change over time such that we can observe something we call spinning?  Such answers would speak to the interactions this hypothetical particle has with the universe, and those interactions could restrict the possible answers for what equations could possibly govern the particle.  If I have a spinning beach ball, I can observe the color of light reflected off it shifting periodically.  If I have a very smooth spinning massful object, then I can observe that it resists torques.  Those sorts of observations of spinning can help narrow down the equations that can govern the particle.
